# Create Javascript Objects with only Keys to make type safe graphql queries

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client, type-safety

I use a graphql-angular client and a graphql-ruby server and would like to build a type-safe system, so other people can write client-side queries and get errors if the query they wrote isn't allowed. I'm not sure if this really is necessary, but the graphql schema is located on the server. So in my understanding if a developer writes an invalid query, the client sends it to the server, there the query will be executed against the schema and the client receives an error, right? I would like the client not to send the query if it will cause an error.

For that I wrote this class:

```
export class RequestQL<request,response> extends Query<response> {
    query:request;
    constructor(apollo,query){
        super(apollo);
        this.query = query;
    }
    document=gql`${convertToString(this.query)}`;
}
```

This class is used by another class that implements the request and response type.
For example like that:

```
export class ListGrammarDataServiceGQL {
    private _query: RequestQL<ListGraphQlRequest, ListGraphQlResponse>;
    constructor(query:ListGraphQlRequest) {
        this._query = new RequestQL<ListGraphQlRequest, ListGraphQlResponse>(Apollo,query);
    }
    request() {
        return this._query.watch()
            .valueChanges.pipe(
                map(result => result.data)
            );
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `gql` function receives a String that looks like a JavaScript object without values. So my first idea was to build a normal object and add random values to the keys like that for example:

```
{
    list: {
        id: 0,
        name: "",
        slug: ""
    }
}
```

Then I tried to write a function (`convertToString`) which parses this object into a graphql query string, but always filling a query with random values you don't need is not what I'm looking for.
The request type could look like this:

```
export interface ListGraphQlRequest {
    list: {
        id
        name
        slug?
        programmingLanguageId
        generatedFromId?
    }
}
```

Has anyone got a smart solution for that problem?
What I want to achieve:
- the client should not be able to send an invalid request to the server.
- Developers should directly recognize if they write an invalid query.

additional:
If someone is interested in the convertToString() function there we go:

```
convertToString(obj){
    let str = "";
    Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => {
        if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
            str += key;
            str += this.convertToString(obj[key]);
        }
        else {
            str += `${key}\n`
        }
    })
    return `{\n${str}}`;
}
```